# cannot able to post item into my controller ? why?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using modal window to post the the values to the controller .

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>Users/sms/" id="form" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

buttons

```
<button type="button" id="custom" class="btn btn-warning" disabled="disabled">
    Custom Msg
</button>
<button type="button" id="initial"  class="btn btn-primary">
    Initial
</button>
```

no response in my screen. i cannot able find the error. in popup window showing nothing. when i click the button no response. suggestion please

Comment: Is action of form correct?

Comment: Show full form and not just pieces. Obviously the button has to have type of submit not button but you already said that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Type should be submit instead of button to post the data.

Comment: i changed but no response when i click the button